# Formaction posting on button [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently having an issue with posting method directly on submit buttons. What I need to do is to put two submit buttons in the same form. I've searched a little and found the html "formaction" method. The problem is that on one page, it is working just fine, but not on the other page.

So, this down here is my code that works:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id">
  <button type="submit" formaction="{{route('remove')}}">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

And that one don't:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$q->id}}">
  <button type="button" formaction="{{route('remove')}}">
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px; color: red;"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Someone has any idea why that is happening? I'm searching for this for a while now, but I just found dead ends.

Comment: You can't have two actions on the same form. Create two different forms or use javascript to submit the form to a specific URL based on the button. Or submit them to the same page, but use different values for each submit button.

Comment: Okay. Thank's, man. I've looked up in the w3schools and there was saying that it was supposed to work that way, but I'll adapt my code.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button, it overrides the form's action. It's available only in HTML5, however.

Answer (score 1):

**suggestion**

add a `name=""` for each button, and use `$_POST["name_of_submit"]` to process the form submission. example

```
//1st button
<button type="submit" name="submit1" formaction="{{route('remove')}}">

//2nd button
<button type="submit" name="submit2" formaction="{{route('remove')}}">

if (isset($_POST['submit1'])){
   //do something
 }
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])){
   //do something else
 }
```